# How to retrieve updated browser URL?

Tags: java, selenium

In selenium I want to write test script to sign up process to a specific website.

The process is: enter your email address -> get magic link -> verify received email -> then sign up.

My question is: when I enter my email address, then click a button open a new tab on the browser to enter my email address and password to sign in my gmail account. For now I can enter my email address, then click Next button using the script. But in my case after click on the next button loading a new web page to enter my password but when I try to access the password field displaying

> Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: input[type=password] (tried for 1 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)"

How do I get the new web page url and access password element? I have already tried implicitly/explicitly wait.

```
ArrayList<String> newTb = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(newTb.get(1));   
              
System.out.println("---> 1 " +driver.getCurrentUrl());
              driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofMillis(500));
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"identifierId\"]"));
email.sendKeys("email");
              driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofMillis(500));
WebElement nextBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext"));
nextBtn.click();
driver.switchTo().window(newTb.get(0)).close();   
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofMillis(1000));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[type=password]")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=password]")).sendKeys("your password");
```

Comment: Can you try without this line: driver.switchTo().window(newTb.get(0)).close();   You are switching to the old context and then closing it and driver is not pointing now to the new tab.

Comment: Do you need to enter the email twice? Is the new url static or dynamic?

Comment: @JRichardsz yes first to get the magic link second for login to provided email account

Comment: @AlexKaramfilov Tried without driver.switchTo().window(newTb.get(0)).close(); but result was the same.

Comment: This scenario is like this.. 1. Load a web page
2. Enter your email address and click on the button
3. Load another web page to open Gmail (same tab)
4. Click on that button user redirect to a new tab with a Gmail account login
5. Enter the email address 
6. Click the Next button
7. Load password entering UI but when I print the URL of the web page still receive the username entered web page URL. because of that, I cannot find the elements of that page
(This password enter web page URL is not static it's a dynamic one so I cannot set through my script)